# OrientDB managing multiple graphs

Tags: java, orientdb

In my application I'm using OrientDB for data storage, management and organization. Now I came to a point where I'd like to have multiple graphs in the same DB which are separate from each other. I know that OrientDB has multitenancy partitioning, but as the graphs have to belong to the same user (and vertices will be moved between them) it doesn't fulfill my needs (its meant for organizing data, not for security). There'll be many queries on either graphs.

At the moment I see two ways to accomplish what I need:

- Defining root nodes and traversing from there each time a query is made. I think this will make performance a lot worse than it could be.
- Supplying an indexed property to each vertex to mark which graph it belongs to. This will probably be faster but it also means having more maintainance and opportunities for bugs and inconsistencies.

Are there more/better options? I'm using Java, so maybe Gremlin has something to offer?

**Edit** *Example Usecase*: a lot of data is generated in highly concentrated intervals. As pruning, making connections, etc. requires a lot of time I won't be able to do this live besides some basic connections (e.g. links for timeseries data). So my idea was to store the data first in a temporary graph and when I have some time I'd take all datapoints from there, do my calculations and move them to the persistent graph.

Comment: Can you give an example of your use case?

Comment: Please see my edited question for a more specific example :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have one root vertex per user and then connect all the subgraphs to this root vertex. So when you need to traverse the graph, start form that root vertex.

Comment: Another solution could be to use different clusters per sub-graph. In this way sub graphs would be separated by the main one at physical level. `alter class Person addcluster Person_X`. Then you can save the vertex in Person_X: `create vertex Person cluster Person_X ...`

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve a vertex from a specific cluster?